# Cannot type backslash (\) in Vim

Tags: macos, iterm2

I am starting to work with vim in iterm2 on macOS. 
Whenever I am in insert mode and try to type a backslash, the cursor jumps to the buttom of the Terminal-window and a forward slash appears.
I have no problem typing a forward slash..

I have tried to find a solution, but couldn't find anything that would help me so far.

Do you have an idea for a solution?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Before going further are you sure that it doesn't come from your vimrc? (See [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841)) Have you tried to reproduce the problem with another terminal emulator?

Comment: To try with another terminal was very helpful.
The standard macOS Terminal worked fine - so I checked the iterm settings and removed the backslash under General -> Characters considered part of word for selection
Now I can type a backslash without any problems..

Comment: I'm glad you fixed your problem. I'm closing this question as off topic because the problem came from the terminal and not vim itself.